# Qt QAbstractModel looking for data

Tags: sql, qt, model, qabstracttablemodel

I have my own `QAbstractTableModel` connected to SQLite. I get data from database and write it to my list by column name. I don't want handle to my table by SQL query when I'm looking for data.

What do you think about? Is it normal?

Please give me some advice.

Comment: You should try to rewrite that question, I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you just looking for [QSqlTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html) ? It's in the doc along with [other Qt Sql classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtsql.html) such as QSqlRelationalTableModel.

Comment: My question is that I get data from sqlite and write them to model and when i searching any data for exp someone's name i dont want write sql command i wanna find them using my model

Answer (score 1):

To search the data in a model you can use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). You set your model as source model for the proxy model, and display the proxy model in a "search results" view.

You can use `setFilterRegExp()` and `setFilterKeyColumn()` to specify for instance the name you are looking for and your "name" column. You can also subclass it if you want more complex filtering. There is [an example in the doc](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/itemviews-customsortfiltermodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. No, QtSQL module doesn't provide any [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), so you have to write SQL queries on your own.
2. However, you can use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) (or subclass it, or even put filtering code in your subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`) for searching/filtering. But I advise you not to do so, because relational databases may (and with high probability will) optimize your search.